# Extract value out of query Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-execution-plan

I have got a query:

```
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
SELECT *
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
ORDER BY CarrierTrackingNumber DESC
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
--OPTION(MAXDOP 1, RECOMPILE)
SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

I want to show the CXPACKET wait time of this query since I am executing it with more than one logical processor.

If i right click on the execution plan and show it as an XML i can find the value.

However i want to do that with a query and just extract the CXPacketWaitTime and not do it manually.
Using that:

```
SELECT ExecutionPlan.value('(/ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/StmtSimple/QueryPlan/WaitStats/Wait[@WaitType="CXPACKET"]/@WaitTimeMs)[1]', 'int') AS CXPacketWaitTime, ExecutionPlan
FROM (SELECT top 1 CAST(query_plan as XML) as ExecutionPlan
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
    WHERE qs.last_execution_time >= DATEADD(minute, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY qs.last_execution_time DESC
    ) AS QP
```

did not work.
I get NULL, the correct query plan. However when opening the correct plan and then again with right click show execution plan xml there is NOT a cxpacket wait, hence the NULL result.

So my question is: How can i get this value?
and why do the XML's differ?

Comment: The execution plan in that DMV is the cached plan so it won't contain any runtime stats relating to any individual execution (such as actual row counts or wait stats). You would need to capture the actual execution plan at time of execution by `STATISTICS XML ON` or extended events to get this value - or look at the aggregated wait stats by execution plan in query store

Comment: May be easier to just snapshot `sys.dm_exec_session_wait_stats WHERE session_id = @@SPID` before and after your execution and get the diffs depending on how you are trying to use this

Comment: Or there is also `dm_exec_query_plan_stats` if you have `DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION SET LAST_QUERY_PLAN_STATS = ON`

Comment: Thank you! I have used the snapshot approach and it works. I think this is quite simple and very useful Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the namespace.

You should also take into account multiple statements in the batch, and statements which are not `SimpleStmt`.

```sql
WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan'
)
SELECT
  x.stmt.value('(QueryPlan/WaitStats/Wait[@WaitType="CXPACKET"]/@WaitTimeMs)[1]', 'int') AS CXPacketWaitTime,
  QP.ExecutionPlan
FROM (
    SELECT top (1) CAST(query_plan as XML) as ExecutionPlan
    FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
    CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(qs.plan_handle) AS qp
    WHERE qs.last_execution_time >= DATEADD(minute, -1, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY qs.last_execution_time DESC
) AS QP
CROSS APPLY QP.ExecutionPlan.nodes('ShowPlanXML/BatchSequence/Batch/Statements/*') x(stmt);
```

Having said that, I don't think the plans contained in `sys.dm_exec_query_stats` actually have wait stats. You probably need the Query Store DMVs to get that information.

Comment: `dm_exec_query_plan` has the compile time representation so won't have any `WaitStats`

Comment: Added a note re that